# csvファイルをvue.jsを用いてブラウザに出力させたい

Tags: python, javascript, csv

現在、db形式で記録されている音ゲーのスコアをhtmlに出力させてwebで閲覧するタイプのスコアサイトを作ろうと思っています。

保存されているdb形式のファイルにはタイトルの代わりに曲名と連動したハッシュが記録されているのでスクレイピングをして得られたデータをPythonのスクリプトを用いてCSV形式に変換することができたのですが、そのCSVをhtmlにしてブラウザで閲覧する方法が分からないのでご教授いただきたいです。

・CSVファイルの形

```
タイトル(差分名),発狂難易度,判定ランク,クリアタイプ,スコアランク,EXスコア,perfect,great,good,bad,poor,maxcombo,最小BP,プレイ回数,スコアレート
la noche (end of mix),0,EASY,Hard,AA,4543,2001,541,77,25,36,847/2661,61,36,85.36
gravitronicⅠ -ANOTHER-,0,NORMAL,Hard,AA,3386,1500,386,93,29,9,1103/2013,38,22,84.1
Milly Barll,0,NORMAL,Hard,A,3111,1277,557,142,17,16,523/2000,33,6,77.78
Merry Christmas Mr.DO,0,NORMAL,Easy,A,2596,1084,428,224,73,37,617/1823,104,20,71.2
Into the sunset [ANOTHER],0,NORMAL,Easy,C,1174,454,266,228,204,134,102/1200,305,7,48.92
(以下計1036個のデータが並ぶ)
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これらが参考になるかも。 [VueでCSVファイルをテーブル表示してみた](https://qiita.com/Kackie/items/e732f8e76382c011812b), [vue.jsでcsvファイルのデータ抽出表示とオセロ](https://qiita.com/tantai/items/5cf98364efa4a80324bd)

Comment: もう少し具体的に「どのような出力結果を得たいのか」も質問文に含めると回答が付きやすいと思います。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて見直してみてください。

Comment: すいません解決しました...ありがとうございました。